# Cross Site Access Not Allowed (using Django 2.1.5)

Tags: django-rest-framework, django-2.1, django-cors-headers

I am working on an app using Django 2.1.5 with DRF 3.9.1 and on firefox browser console, I am getting this error:

```
downloadable font: download failed (font-family: "FontAwesome" style:normal weight:400 stretch:100 src index:2): bad URI or cross-site access not allowed source: http://softpro-admin-templates.websitedesignmarketingagency.com/assets/vendor_components/font-awesome/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.woff?v=4.7.0
```

After some googling, I came across this link https://github.com/ottoyiu/django-cors-headers/

As mentioned in the document I have installed the package and made the following modifications in the settings file:

```
    CORS_ORIGIN_ALLOW_ALL = True

    CORS_ALLOW_CREDENTIALS = True

    MIDDLEWARE = [
        'corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware', #added at the top
         -----

    ]

    INSTALLED_APPS = [

    'corsheaders',

    ]
```

But still, I am getting the same error. Can someone help me with this issue?

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you're not the owner of softpro-admin-templates.websitedesignmarketingagency.com

Somewhere on your site, you're using `fontawesome` version 4.7.0 ([A common icon font](https://fontawesome.com/)) but providing the above host as the source for this font. Due to [CORS policies in most browsers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS), the host has to specifically allow this if the site the request originates from (yours) was fetched from a different domain (origin).

As the maintainer(s) of softpro-admin-templates.websitedesignmarketingagency.com likely don't know anything about your site, this hasn't been done. Change the src of `fontawesome` to your own server or [the CDN suggested by `fontawesome`](https://fontawesome.com/start) to solve this.

Comment: Yes, I am not the owner and will surely look into this. Thanks for the reply @Mark.

Comment: I'm sorry, I assumed you got a template from `softpro-admin-templates.websitedesignmarketingagency.com` and were having problems with it. 

But since it is your site, fix the CORS header on `softpro-admin-templates.websitedesignmarketingagency.com` (the source) and you should be good to go. Changing the CORS headers on your Django app (the requesting app)  won't help as CORS headers are there to protect the source.